# m2eclipse does not show workspace project dependencies but shows transitive dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, dependency-management, eclipse-wtp

I am having trouble with m2eclipse.

I am using Eclipse 3.6.2, m2eclipse 0.12.1 and m2extras for subclipse 0.12.0 and for wtp 0.11.1.

I have projects A(jar packaging), B(jar) and C(war). I have all three in my workspace and **NOT** in local or remote repo (double checked). C has dependencies on A and B. A has dependencies on some libraries (say X and Y) and B has dependencies on some other libraries (say P, Q and R). C has too dependencies on external libraries (say U, V, W). What Eclipse is showing to me in "Maven Dependecies" is following:

```
A
- Maven Dependencies
  + (jar icon) X
  + (jar icon) Y

B
- Maven Dependencies
  + (jar icon) P
  + (jar icon) Q
  + (jar icon) R

C
- Maven Dependencies
  + (jar icon) U
  + (jar icon) V
  + (jar icon) W
  + (jar icon) X
  + (jar icon) Y
  + (jar icon) P
  + (jar icon) Q
  + (jar icon) R
```

This is a problem because in project C Eclipse is not aware of the code in projects A and B. I expect the project setup for C to look like this

```
C
- Maven Dependencies
  + (jar icon) U
  + (jar icon) V
  + (jar icon) W
  + (jar icon) X
  + (jar icon) Y
  + (jar icon) P
  + (jar icon) Q
  + (jar icon) R
  + (folder icon) A
  + (folder icon) B
```

What is the worst thing is that until I recently updated the project with the latest code from SVN the project setup for C looked like it should, and now it does not. And I remember having this problem earlier, but I cannot remember how I solved it.

I have yet another project - D with jar packaging, and it's showing like this in project explorer:

```
D
- Maven Depenedencies
  + (jar icon) X
  + (jar icon) Y
  + (jar icon) I
  + (jar icon) J
  + (folder icon) A
```

What is the remedy for this situation? I cannot remember what I have done previous time. Maybe I have installed Eclipse from scratch?

Comment: Did you check the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" in the Properties -> Maven section of your project?

Comment: @reef Of course. If I uncheck it, then all dependencies from A and B are missing, only U, V and W remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Someone in the team checked in following configuration files:

```
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
```

After I deleted them m2eclipse could setup the projects correctly.

Comment: I have only now seen your answer. You *could* be very well right and I'll give you accepted answer. But see my answer to what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I wanted my related projects to appear under **Maven Dependencies** with blue folder icons, rather than jar icons, indicating that the projects were referencing each other in Eclipse, and not just linking to their jars from my local Maven repository.

I resolved the problem by opening the POM in Eclipse, reordering the dependencies, and saving.  M2Eclipse reprocessed the dependencies and fixed everything.  I'm not sure why it worked, but it did.

Prior to this action, I also deleted the Eclipses projects' repo folders where the undesirable JARs were coming from.  Things still weren't working afterwards, so I don't know if that had anything to do with why the fix mentioned above worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have deleted my workspace, checked in projects again and now the set up for project A is showing up like this:

```
C
- Maven Dependencies
  + (jar icon) U
  + (jar icon) V
  + (jar icon) W
  + (jar icon) X
  + (jar icon) Y
  + (jar icon) P
  + (jar icon) Q
  + (jar icon) R
- Web App Libraries
  + (jar icon) R
  + (jar icon) V
  + (jar icon) X
  + (jar icon) W
  + (jar icon) Y
  + (jar icon) P
  + (jar icon) U
  + (jar icon) Q
  + (folder icon) A
  + (folder icon) B
```

It looks like that dependent projects are now shown in Web App Libraries. I believe that it is possible that "Dynamic Web Module" facet was not present earlier when I checked in new code from SVN which possibly triggered Maven > Update Project Configuration.

Also now I use version 0.12.0 version of m2extras for wtp.